# sprite will only move to my first waypoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a sprite to move along a set of waypoints after spawned, but whenever the sprite gets to the first waypoint it just stops.

[Inspector for the road object that contains all the waypoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKu0d.png)

```
public class MoveEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    private int currentWaypoint = 0;
    private float lastWaypointSwitchTime;
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lastWaypointSwitchTime = Time.time;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // 1 
        Vector3 startPosition = waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position;
        Vector3 endPosition = waypoints[currentWaypoint + 1].transform.position;
        // 2 
        float pathLength = Vector3.Distance(startPosition, endPosition);
        float totalTimeForPath = pathLength / speed;
        float currentTimeOnPath = Time.time - lastWaypointSwitchTime;
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, currentTimeOnPath / totalTimeForPath);
        // 3 
        if (gameObject.transform.position.Equals(endPosition))
        {
            if (currentWaypoint < waypoints.Length - 2)
            {
                // 3.a 
                currentWaypoint++;
                lastWaypointSwitchTime = Time.time;
                // TODO: Rotate into move direction
            }
            else
            {
                // 3.b 
                Destroy(gameObject);

                AudioSource audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(audioSource.clip, transform.position);
                // TODO: deduct health
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the sprite and the waypoints have the same Z axis value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem try replacing

```
if (gameObject.transform.position.Equals(endPosition))
```

with

```
if (Vector2.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, endPosition) < 0.2f)
```

This should fix the issue where the gameObject stops at the first waypoint. This is because the position of the gameObject and the waypoint may not be the same down to the decimal, so this code will check if it's in a range of 0.2 from the next waypoint.

Also calling these two lines:

```
Vector3 startPosition = waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position;
Vector3 endPosition = waypoints[currentWaypoint + 1].transform.position;
```

In the update function isn't very efficient. You could instead calculate these values in the start function, and also when you  reach the next waypoint.

Hope this helps!

Comment: why `0.2` though? That range might be quite huge depending on the app ... you could use [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) or alternatively cast `if((Vector2)gameObject.transform.position == (Vector2)endPosition)` which uses `0.00001`

Comment: It doesn't have to be 0.2, and you can change the value to anything depending on your own game. The point is that the position of the gameObject and the waypoint may not be **exactly** the same.